# jQuery not work in responsive in magento

Tags: jquery, magento, jquery-inputmask

I need to change input format for example, zip code (99999-999), so i used jquery.inputmask.bundle.js from github.

here is github path
https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

this script work perfect in browser but not work in responsive, i mean in mobile device.and here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#searchd').inputmask('99999-999');
    }); 
</script>
```

What i am doing wrong please let me know.

Comment: Add more information to get helpful responses

Comment: Hi @dbmitch , i have edited my comment.please check it, hope this is help.